# Adicionar fila al final que sume totales de columnas en POSTGRESQL

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente consulta, en postgresql y psycopg2:

```
cur.execute("""select admin_eps.nombre_eps, admin_eps.nit_eps,   

                   SUM(COALESCE((sbmEmp/30*diastmes + sbmEmp/240*1.25*hon + sbmEmp/240*1.25*hed 
                   + sbmEmp/240*1.75*hen + sbmEmp/240*2*hofd + sbmEmp/240*2.25*hofn 
                   + sbmEmp/240*2.50*hefd + sbmEmp/240*2.75*hefn)*0.040)) AS DEDU_EPS,

                   SUM(COALESCE((sbmEmp/30*diastmes + sbmEmp/240*1.25*hon + sbmEmp/240*1.25*hed 
                   + sbmEmp/240*1.75*hen + sbmEmp/240*2*hofd + sbmEmp/240*2.25*hofn 
                   + sbmEmp/240*2.50*hefd + sbmEmp/240*2.75*hefn)*0.085)) AS GASTO_EPS

                   from empleado

                   INNER JOIN novedad_nomina ON novedad_nomina.numdocempnov = empleado.numdocemp
                   INNER JOIN admin_eps ON admin_eps.nit_eps = empleado.nit_eps                

                   GROUP BY admin_eps.nit_eps,
                          admin_eps.nombre_eps                                   

                           """)

    conn.commit()
```

> Que me genera la siguiente consulta:

>

```
╒══════════════╤═══════════╤═════════════╤═════════════╕
│ nombre_eps   │   nit_eps │ dedu_eps    │ gasto_eps   │
╞══════════════╪═══════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ EPS SURA     │ 800088702 │ $48,218.10  │ $102,463.46 │
├──────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ MEDIMAS EPS  │ 901097473 │ $78,082.88  │ $165,926.12 │
├──────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ NUEVA EPS    │ 900156264 │ $169,648.51 │ $360,503.09 │
├──────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ COOMEVA EPS  │ 805000427 │ $146,797.86 │ $311,945.45 │
╘══════════════╧═══════════╧═════════════╧═════════════╛
```

Como puedo adicionar al final del la consulta me sume o totalice las columnas dedu_eps y gasto_eps, agradezco lo que puedan orientar, este seria el resultado que busco, gracias:

```
╒══════════════╤═══════════╤═════════════╤═════════════╕
│ nombre_eps   │   nit_eps │ dedu_eps    │ gasto_eps   │
╞══════════════╪═══════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ EPS SURA     │ 800088702 │ $48,218.10  │ $102,463.46 │
├──────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ MEDIMAS EPS  │ 901097473 │ $78,082.88  │ $165,926.12 │
├──────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ NUEVA EPS    │ 900156264 │ $169,648.51 │ $360,503.09 │
├──────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ COOMEVA EPS  │ 805000427 │ $146,797.86 │ $311,945.45 │
╘══════════════╧═══════════╧═════════════╧═════════════╛
**Totales                   $295,949.49   $940,838.12**
```

Comment: Pero esto es un problema de la vista, o vos realmente queres que SQL hago esa tabla, para lo cual habria que hacer algo muy raro?

Comment: No olvides que esa tabla es una query y solo quiero agregar esa suma como fila al final de la consulta, si fuera transponer de filas a columnas seria mas sencillo, pero es lo contrario(columnas a filas)

Comment: El formato de salida lo hace parecer una tabla, pero es una consulta

Comment: a lo que me refiero, a que esa consulta, se puede resolver por la vista. para resolverla en el programa que estes usando para ver la consulta, se puede, pero no es una consulta que uno usaria productivamente...

Comment: ok, puede ser, pero eso no me ayuda, me confunde, y solo entiendo con ejemplos y graficamente,?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta al final de tu consulta usar las opciones de CUBE y ROLLUP, creo que te servirian para ejecutar lo que necesitas.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS

Comment: Ok , lo intentare y te aviso como funciono

Comment: Dale,mucha suerte.

Comment: Intente pero el orden que me da cube y rollup no es igual a lo que necesito, no resumen los totales como lo muestro en la imagen

Comment: se debe considerar tambien que las columnas dedu_eps y gasto_eps, son nombres de consulta (alias) y no pertenecen a ninguna columna de tabla?

Comment: Creo que no habria problema¿ Por que ?